# ChineseLunar calendar system mystery

Tags: date-and-time

I tried to make a custom holiday calendar for the Korean Stock Exchange.
And I found that the built-in "ChineseLunar" calendar system gives me an awkward result.

The code is

```
DateList /@ DayRange[{2012, 1, 1}, {2014, 3, 1}, "Holiday", HolidayCalendar -> {"ChineseLunar" -> {{True &, (#1 == 1) &, (#1 == 1) &}}}]
```

And the result is

```
{{2012, 1, 23, 0, 0, 0.}, {2014, 1, 31, 0, 0, 0.}}
```

Where is the date for 2013?

And what surprised me is

```
DateList /@ DayRange[{2012, 1, 1}, {2014, 3, 1}, "Holiday", HolidayCalendar -> {"ChineseLunar" -> {{True &, (#1 == 1) &, (#1 == 1||#1 == 2) &}}}]
```

gives me

```
{{2012, 1, 23, 0, 0, 0.}, {2012, 1, 24, 0, 0, 0.}, {2013, 2, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, {2014, 1, 31, 0, 0, 0.}}
```

I supposed it should return two dates for each year.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @Nasser Unexpected answer :) If so, any alternatives?

Comment: Well, it is clear it is a bug. It missed a whole year. But I never used this command, just looked it up now. You can wait for others to suggest something. Might be useful to send email to support@wolfram.com with small example showing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a perfect but working solution.
I installed a python package "lunisolar"

```
ConvertCalendar[date_List, "Gregorian" -> "ChineseLunar"] := 
  Flatten@Import[StringJoin[
    "!/usr/local/bin/python -c 'from lunisolar import ChineseDate;c = \
ChineseDate.from_gregorian(", DateString[date, 
 {"Year", ",", "Month", ",","Day"}], ");print \"%s,%s,%s,%s\" % (c.year, c.month, c.day, \
c.is_leap_month)'"], "CSV"]

ConvertCalendar[date_List, "ChineseLunar" -> "Gregorian"] :=
Flatten@Import[
  StringJoin[
    "!/usr/local/bin/python -c 'from lunisolar import ChineseDate;g = \
ChineseDate.from_chinese(",
    DateString[
      Take[date, 3], {"Year", ",", "Month", ",", "Day", ",",
      Last[date]}],
    ").gregorian_date;print \"%s,%s,%s\" % (g.year, g.month, g.day)'"], "CSV"]
```

Example:

```
In[1] = ConvertCalendar[{2014, 1, 1}, "Gregorian" -> "ChineseLunar"]
Out[1]= {2013, 12, 1, "False"}
In[2] = ConvertCalendar[{2014, 1, 1, "False"}, "ChineseLunar" -> "Gregorian"]
Out[2]= {2014, 1, 31}
```

"False" means it's not a leap month.